# Cookies and cookie consent boxes when crawling webpage with BeautifulSoup and Requests in Python

Tags: python, html, cookies, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm writing a script that's supposed to crawl price comparison pages [like this one](https://www.heise.de/preisvergleich/?cat=gra16_512&xf=9810_16+0020314+-+RTX+3070) which is supposed to run every x seconds and alert myself via an email whenever a certain item is available for a price lower than X. Sadly, I'm unable to extract the data I want (in the name and price columns, html references are following) and believe the problem is caused by a cookie consent box.

When manually looking at the html of the page when checking it through my browser, I have seen that the name and price of the listed items are:

```
<a href="inno3d-geforce-rtx-3070-ichill-x3-c30703-08d6x-1710va38-a2408388.html?hloc=at&amp;hloc=de" class="productlist__link">
<span class="notrans">
INNO3D GeForce RTX 3070 iCHILL X3, 8GB GDDR6, HDMI, 3x DP (C30703-08D6X-1710VA38)
</span>
</a>
<div class="productlist__item productlist__description">
<p class="x"><span class="notrans">Anschlüsse: 1x HDMI 2.1, 3x DisplayPort 1.4a • Grafik: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 (Desktop), 8GB GDDR6 • Chip: GA104-300-A1 "Ampere", 46SM, 392mm² • Fertigung: 8nm (Samsung) • Chiptakt: 1500MHz, Boost: 1785MHz • Speicher: 8GB GDDR6, 1750MHz, 256bit, ...</span></p>
</div>
</div>
```

and

```
<span class="gh_price"> <span class="notrans">€ 609,00</span>
</span>
</div>
```

for name and price respectively. Using `BeautifulSoup.find_all("a", class_"productlist__link")` or `BeautifulSoup.find_all("span", class_="gh_price")` can extract them out of the given examples easily. EDIT: For clarification, I'm using `x=BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")` and calling `x.find_all(...)` afterwards like in the code that follows.

I'm crawling the page with the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.heise.de/preisvergleich/?cat=gra16_512&xf=9810_16+0020314+-+RTX+3070"
params_ = {"hloc":"de", "hloc":"at", "v":"k"}
session = requests.session()
response = session.get(URL, params=params_, cookies=cookies_)
response.raise_for_status()
session.close()
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
```

But when using `soup.find_all(...)` like before, my list of results is an empty list. After looking at the `response.text` in the browser I noticed the site was barely readible except for the cookie consent for, so I copied all cookies my browser used into a dict called `cookies_={...}` and added them to the request(as already seen in the code part above), but the response was still unreadable and the cookie consent form was still there and no data was extracted.

So, my question now is what I'm doing wrong trying to get rid of the consent box and if there's anything else I'm missing. As of my understanding, even with the consent box there, the list of items should still be in the `response` and my code should still extract it (but doesn't) so I'm guessing I'm also missing some other ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need the cookies, IMHO. The site replies with the full HTML with a simple request. Even headers are not needed.

Here's an example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tabulate import tabulate

url = "https://www.heise.de/preisvergleich/?cat=gra16_512&xf=9810_16+0020314+-+RTX+3070"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
products = [
    f"https://www.heise.de/preisvergleich/{p['href']}" for p
    in soup.find_all("a", class_="productlist__link")
]
prices = [
    p.getText(strip=True) for p
    in soup.find_all("span", class_="gh_price")
]

print(tabulate(zip(products, prices), headers=["Product URL", "Price"]))
```

This outputs:

```
Product URL                                                                                                                      Price
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  ----------
https://www.heise.de/preisvergleich/gigabyte-geforce-rtx-3070-gaming-oc-8g-gv-n3070gaming-oc-8gd-a2406936.html?hloc=at&hloc=de   € 799,00
https://www.heise.de/preisvergleich/zotac-gaming-geforce-rtx-3070-twin-edge-zt-a30700e-10p-a2363490.html?hloc=at&hloc=de         € 609,00
https://www.heise.de/preisvergleich/gigabyte-aorus-geforce-rtx-3070-master-8g-gv-n3070aorus-m-8gd-a2406973.html?hloc=at&hloc=de  ab€ 889,00
https://www.heise.de/preisvergleich/gigabyte-geforce-rtx-3070-vision-oc-8g-gv-n3070vision-oc-8gd-a2406952.html?hloc=at&hloc=de   € 1095,00
https://www.heise.de/preisvergleich/msi-geforce-rtx-3070-ventus-2x-oc-a2364400.html?hloc=at&hloc=de                              € 1099,00
https://www.heise.de/preisvergleich/palit-geforce-rtx-3070-gamingrock-ne63070019p2-1040g-a2408422.html?hloc=at&hloc=de           € 899,90
https://www.heise.de/preisvergleich/asus-dual-geforce-rtx-3070-oc-a2366124.html?hloc=at&hloc=de                                  ab€ 799,00
https://www.heise.de/preisvergleich/gainward-geforce-rtx-3070-phantom-gs-2201-a2435816.html?hloc=at&hloc=de                      € 769,00
https://www.heise.de/preisvergleich/inno3d-geforce-rtx-3070-twin-x2-oc-n30702-08d6x-1710va32l-a2429903.html?hloc=at&hloc=de      € 699,00
```